# Adafruit Feather unable to upload code

Tags: adafruit

I am using Adafruit Feather RFM69HCW Microcontroller. I am having difficulty uploading code in any Adafruit Feather boards. We have a project that is live on the field and it needs code changes. I have tried everything from holding the reset button while uploading, uploading the basic Blink function, changing USB micro cables, using different Adafruit Feather Boards.

However, I am assuming it has something to do with the Adafruit drivers.

I would really appreciate it if anybody can help me figure out the problem here.

Comment: Doesn't adafruit have a pretty good support forum?

Comment: You don't say which board you have (M0 or 32u4) and you don't tell us what error you are getting.

Comment: `difficulty uploading code` ... this is useless information